Support for complex queries using analyzers
I submitted this as a feature request but perhaps it is best for this to be addressed as a question here.
We have the need to be able to build some more complex search queries that logically combine ands with ors. We can currently achieve some of what we desire by using the _and and _or in a where filter however we then lose the analyzer combining that we get from the main query. We could use regex searches using like within the _and and _or but are concerned about performance and the loss of proper matching that Searchkick is so good at configuring.
We could also build up a more complex search by using the body option but again we would lose the analyzer configuration that Searchkick provides automatically for the main query.
Is there currently a way to combine some of the default behavior one gets for the main query into the subqueries with _or and _and with Searchkick?
It would have been nice for something like:
Ticket.search('*', where: { _or: [{subject: 'complaint'}, {content: 'support'}] })

yields a body like:
{:query=>
  {:bool=>
    {:must=>{:match_all=>{}},
     :filter=>
      [{:bool=>
         {:should=>
           [{:bool=>{:filter=>[{:term=>{:subject=>{:value=>"complaint"}}}]}},
            {:bool=>
              {:filter=>[{:term=>{:content=>{:value=>"support"}}}]}}]}}]}},

Meanwhile, with the main query of:
Ticket.search('complaint support', fields: [:subject, :content], operator: :or, match: :word_start)

we get the following body:
 {:query=>
  {:bool=>
    {:should=>
      [{:dis_max=>
         {:queries=>
           [{:bool=>
              {:must=>
                {:bool=>
                  {:should=>
                    [{:match=>{"subject.word_start"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>10, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search"}}},
                     {:match=>{"subject.word_start"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>1, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search", :fuzziness=>1, :prefix_length=>0, :max_expansions=>3, :fuzzy_transpositions=>true}}}]}},
               :should=>{:match=>{"subject.analyzed"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>10, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search"}}}}}]}},
       {:dis_max=>
         {:queries=>
           [{:bool=>
              {:must=>
                {:bool=>
                  {:should=>
                    [{:match=>{"content.word_start"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>10, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search"}}},
                     {:match=>{"content.word_start"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>1, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search", :fuzziness=>1, :prefix_length=>0, :max_expansions=>3, :fuzzy_transpositions=>true}}}]}},
               :should=>{:match=>{"content.analyzed"=>{:query=>"complaint support", :boost=>10, :operator=>:or, :analyzer=>"searchkick_word_search"}}}}}]}}]}},

Unfortunately the logic is not quite right with the second approach.
Ideally we would get the subqueries with the analyzers embedded in the and/or (must/should) query structure.
